# Matrices with rank 1 over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, finite-fields, matrix-rank

Let $\mathbb{F}_{11}=\{\overline{0},\overline{1},\ldots,\overline{10}\} $  be a finite field and $A=(a_{ij})_{3 \times 3}$ a matrix such that $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{F}_{11}, \ \ \forall \ 1\leq i,j\leq 3$. What is the probability that $rank(A)=1$.

I tried as follows: There is $11^9$ matrices of the described form. If $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in \mathbb{F}_{11}^3$ are the row vectors if $A$, we need that $dimV=1$, where $V=span\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$. So we can choose the vector $v_1$ of $11^3-1$ different ways ($v_1\neq 0$).Now, there are $11$ ways for choose teh vector $v_2$ and $11.11=11^2$  ways for choose the vector $v_3$...Is this idea correct?

Comment: Not quite. The first row of a rank-one matrix can be zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your counting is not entirely correct, as the first row can also be zero (as already commented by user1551). But the basic idea works and refining your argument, we get a correct solution.

**Solution.** If the first row is non-zero ($11^3 - 1$ possibilities), there are $11^2$ possibilities for the other two rows. (The only condition is that they are contained in the span of the first row, which is of size $11$.)
If the first row equals zero and the second row is non-zero ($11^3 - 1$ possibilities), there are $11$ possiblilities for the last row.
If the first two rows are zero, the last row must be nonzero, so $11^3 - 1$ possibilities.
So in total there are
$$
(11^3 - 1) \cdot 11^2 + (11^3 - 1) \cdot 11 + (11^3 - 1) = 176890
$$
rank $1$ matrices, and hence the requested probability equals
$$
\frac{176890}{11^9} \approx 0.00750186\%.
$$

**Alternative 1.**
Knowing a bit more about the combinatorics of finite vector space, you can do it in this way for $n\times n$ matrices of rank $1$ over a general finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$:
The rank of a matrix is the dimension of its row space.
So the number of possible row spaces equals the number $\frac{q^n - 1}{q-1}$ of $1$-dimensional subspaces $W$ of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^n$.
For fixed $W$ the number of $n$-tuples of vectors spanning $W$ equals $q^n - 1$. (Note that $\#W = q$, and the single $n$-tuple $(0,0,0)$ does not span $W$, but all other $n$-tuples over $W$ do.)

Hence the number of rank $1$ matrices of size $n\times n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$ is
$$
\frac{q^n - 1}{q-1} \cdot (q^n - 1) = \frac{(q^n - 1)^2}{q-1}\text{.}
$$

**Alternative 2.**
There is another alternative if you know that a rank $1$ square matrix has always the form $v\cdot w^{\top}$ with non-zero vectors $v,w$. One checks that two such matrices $v\cdot w^{\top}$ and $v' \cdot (w')^\top$ are equal if and only if $v' = \lambda v$ and $w' = \lambda^{-1} w$ with a non-zero scalar $\lambda$. Hence each rank $1$ matrix has $q-1$ representations $v\cdot w^{\top}$, and again we get their number as $\frac{(q^n - 1)^2}{q-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!